# Linking id to person (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of worker.id, worker.first_name, and worker.last_name at 0.0.0.0:3000/workers/all.

I need to make the worker.id a link that would direct to the worker's more detailed info, 0.0.0.0:3000/workers/show?id=x (x is the id of the worker).

I already have the latter working using "@worker = db.find_by_id(params[:id])" in the Controller so when I type /workers/show?id=5 I get into that worker's detailed info.

The code in View:

```
<li><%= link_to(worker.id) %>, <%= worker.first_name %>, <%= worker.last_name %></li>
```

... creates the /workers/all list properly: "123, Ted, Testman". I just need to make the /workers/all list of ids(123 in above example) into links that direct to the proper worker's info, /workers/show?id=123 in this case. With the above code the id is linking back into /workers/all.

Answer (score 1):

If `worker` is an ActiveRecord model, you don't even need to use `worker_path`:

```
<%= link_to(worker.id, worker) %>
```

Comment: Can't get this or CDub's suggestions to work. However if I use <%= link_to(worker.id, :id => worker.id) %> I get it working almost properly, the id links to workers/all?id=x. Now I just need to somehow swich the "all" into "show".

Answer (score 0):

You want to link to the `worker_path` for that worker, passing `id` as a parameter:

```
<li><%= link_to(worker_path(worker, :id => worker.id) %>, <%= worker.first_name %>, <%= worker.last_name %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `link_to helper` incorrectly,

it should be something like

`link_to "#{worker.first_name} #{worker.last_name}", worker`

and probably as the explanation you have give in the question, just `scaffolding' the worker should give you most of the things you want 'out of the box' , this is a good read about [scaffolding](http://viget.com/extend/rails-3-generators-scaffolding)

read more here about [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

HTH